# Android Studio design view pixelated when zoom other than 100%

Tags: android, android-studio

This didn't happen before I installed the latest version. I have gone to Android Studio->Properties->Compatibility and tried just about every possible permutation (although I really don't know which settings would likely solve the problem).

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reasons for this issue, please ref [official doc about troubleshoot](https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot#blurry_or_pixelated_elements_on_high-density_displays).